# How to solve IPAddr object has no attribute split error

Tags: python, python-2.7, sdn, pox

Here is my code

```
from pox.lib.addresses import IPAddr
def ip_atoi(st):
"""
function to convert ip address to integer value
"""
  st=st.split(".")
  return int("%02x%02x%02x%02x"%(int(st[0]),int(st[1]),int(st[2]),int(st[3])),16)
```

1. when i run this script in pox controller i am getting error saying

   ```
   AttributeError: 'IPAddr' object has no attribute 'split'
   ```

Comment: Seems straightforward to me. `st` is an `IPAddr` object, and `IPAddr` objects don't have a `split` method, so it crashes when you try to call `split` on an `IPAddr`.

Comment: There is a method in the IPAddr class `toStr()`. You should call first `st.toStr()` and then split it. line 294 https://github.com/noxrepo/pox/blob/carp/pox/lib/addresses.py

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `st` is not a string, but an `IPAddr` object. What you might want to do instead is:

```
st = str(st).split(".")
```